# Why does my rapid fire TNT cannon always explode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I watch that video on YouTube, it shows you how to make a rapid fire tnt cannon. I made it, but when I activate it, it just explodes and the water flow out! I did that in survival mode, so I lost all the stuff to build that cannon because it exploded. Heres the video: [Rapid Fire TNT Cannon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLmuUFVovsw)

Heres some pictures:

[image: The Cannon I Made (front)]

[image: The Cannon I Made (back)]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried building it in Creative mode to perfect it first? It's easier to figure out flaws when you can quickly rebuild.

Comment: yes but it also exploded in creative.

Comment: I think I started it wrong or something

Comment: I'm not sure we can properly answer this without a look at your reproduction of the cannon in that video. As the one in the video seems to (largely) work, the only conclusions I can come to is that either you copied the design (or the method for activating it) poorly, or an update to Minecraft since March made some part of that design not work.

Comment: yes I copied the design as in the video

Comment: @MinecraftGamer upload some pics of your cannon

Comment: but why does it explode??? I put the dispensers right, I put the pressure plates right, I put the water right, and I put the redstone right. I also put the redstone on top of the other three dispensers, not just the three on the bottom (just to make it easier). Then I put the one redstone there on the ground and it just explodes!!!

Comment: @qwertyk31 how do you upload pictures from my minecraft screen?

Comment: is it press F1 to take screenshot?

Comment: wait... is it F1 or F2?

Comment: @MinecraftGamer try both

Comment: F2 thanks. but that doesn't do anything. I go to my folders in the computer and I don't see the screenshot anywhere

Comment: You could always try the **Print Screen** key, and then paste into MSpaint.

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: where is that? I don't see that key anywhere. And I don't have a printer. What is MSpaint???

Comment: @MinecraftGamer are you playing PC, Pocket or X-Box 360 Minecraft

Comment: @MinecraftGamer The button you are looking for will be labeled PrtSc SysRq, or something similar. It should be on the top row to the right of the F12 key. Look at your cannon and press it. That will take a picture of it- don't worry, it has nothing to do with your printer. Once you've done that, open Paint and press ctrl-v. The picture should now appear in Paint. Does that work?

Comment: @MinecraftGamer - It goes to the "screenshots" folder in your .minecraft folder.

Comment: @Memor-X im playing PC

Comment: @Studoku I don't see it. it only shows to the right of the F12 key insert/scroll, and delete. I have a laptop

Comment: @Dinopet123 I search the folder but it says no results

Comment: @MinecraftGamer - search %appdata% in the start menu and .minecraft should be at the top.

Comment: @MinecraftGamer i have a Lenovo Laptop and my PrtSc button (print screen) between the Delete and Pause Keys,  i also have a orange Fn key and a bunch of keys have orange text on them, ie. my NumLock is NmLk in orange on my Delete Key so for me to use it i need to hold the Fn key when i press Delete, it might be something similar with you from your Print Screen Key

Comment: @Memor-X ??????? dafaq? I no have any of these keys. mine is HP laptop

Comment: @Dinopet123 ok I found it

Comment: @Dinopet123 is it roaming?

Comment: @Dinopet123 I press .minecraft when I pressed roaming. now which folder do I go to?

Comment: @Memor-X I don't have the pause key, and the PrtSc key

Comment: @Memor-X you mean the home key? I think on the bottom of the home key is the little rectangle thing and inside the rectangle is the PrtSc key?: https://www.replacementlaptopkeys.com/images/hp_dv6_1000_laptop_key.jpg

Comment: @Memor-X but I press it it doesn't work. I don't have a printer

Comment: @MinecraftGamer that would bit it, the image is kinda poor as i can barely read the text on the keys but on the right of your left side Ctrl Key you have another key in a white box, if you hold that down and press the key with PrtSc in the white box that will take a screen shot of your screen, then just paste that into Paint or any image editing program and put it up so people can help you out in your question, after all, you probably wont get an answer unless you show us images

Comment: @Memor-X it doesn't work and I said I don't have Paint or a printer

Comment: @MinecraftGamer you need to press and hold the key between your left side Ctrl Key and Windows Key, this will take a screen shot of your screen which you need to paste into a image editing program, if your running Windows paint can be found by clicking on the Start Button and going to All Programs > Accessories > Paint, if you really don't have it then you'll have to rely on Minecraft's screenshot taken where it saves the files in the screenshot folder....though i find it surprising you don't have Paint, i thought it was standard with any version of Windows

Comment: @Memor-X I no have. where you download?

Comment: @MinecraftGamer .......yeh that is weird. since Paint is normally standard i have no idea where you can download it, you can use any other image editing program however this is not the place for that

Comment: @MinecraftGamer i guess your next option is to use the Minecraft Screenshots files which Dinopet123 was talking about, i would help in this matter however it seems that the folder is created when you have taken at least 1 screenshot ingame which i have not done on my laptop Aura and she's been devoid of a proper shut down for over a week and i have Dreamweaver running which means Minecraft is going to take forever to boot up for me

Comment: @MinecraftGamer on my main gaming PC C.C i do have the screenshots folder, i think it's in the main folder for the .minecraft folder however as i said it must be created automatically after you take a screenshot in the game, after you get that image post it in your question so someone can help with your question

Comment: @MinecraftGamer - There should be a folder called "screenshots" located within the .minecraft folder.

Comment: @Dinopet123 I found it now: Start Menu > Search: %appdata% > Roaming > .minecraft > screenshots.

Comment: but wheres the screenshot I took?

Comment: ok this computer seriously has a problem

Comment: wait, found it!!!

Comment: I'm no expert but shouldn't it be made of obsidian?

Comment: @Studoku yes it can be made out of any block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just re-watched the video, and compared it to what you are showing us here. I think I may have figured it out.

The video instructs you to place the final 3 bits of redstone on the second set of dispensers while the clock is running. This creates a delay between the explosion of the projectile TNT, and the propellant TNT. If you already have redstone on top of the second set of dispensers when the clock starts, the projectile TNT will be dispensed at the same time as the propellant TNT, and go off at the same time as your propellant. That little delay is critical to ensure that your cannon doesn't blow up in place, and that your projectile will actually move forward.

Comment: wait, so you destroy the redstone on the top three dispensers? And then you put the redstone on the ground? And then you quickly place the three redstone on the top set of dispensers? Is that correct? I think it is. I tried it now and it looks really cool.

Comment: @MinecraftGamer That is correct.

Comment: I put the three redstone on the set of dispensers on top the first time because I want to make it easier. Then I just put the redstone on the ground the first time. So that was why it exploded. I want to make it easier because my computer sometimes lags.